# "Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When I run the endpoint on Postman it works fine and returns the result it posted, but when I use TEST on AWS lambda it returns the error "Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0". 
I checked the Use Lambda proxy on API gateway inside integration request, would that effect something?

Here is my lambda function

```
'use strict';

const uuid = require('uuid');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk'); // eslint-disable-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies

const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

module.exports.create = (event, context, callback) => {
  const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
  const data = JSON.parse(event.body);

  if (typeof data.phoneNumber !== 'string') {
    console.error('Validation Failed');
    callback(null, {
      statusCode: 400,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
      body: 'Couldn\'t create item.',
    });
    return;
  }

  const params = {
    TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE,
    Item: {
      id: uuid.v1(),

      phoneNumber: data.phoneNumber,
      sub: data.sub,

      createdAt: timestamp,
      updatedAt: timestamp,
    },
  };

  console.log(params);

  // write the lakeSubscription to the database
  dynamoDb.put(params, (error) => {
    // handle potential errors

    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
      callback(null, {
        statusCode: error.statusCode || 501,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
        body: 'Couldn\'t create in dynamoDb.',
      });
      return;
    }

    // create a response
    const response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(params.Item),
    };
    callback(null, response);
  });
};
```

Comment: Are you sure you're receiving in `event.body` what you think you should be receiving? Have you tried logging it?

Comment: Jason, it usually means there's a problem with the input JSON format. Can you validate your test JSON? 

It may help you.

Comment: @HassanMurtaza Hey thanks for the reply. Yes I validated it and it posts to the dynamodb fine but the logs are saying "SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0". Is there anything else you would suggest to check?

Comment: @9000 I'm logging it but just the error populates. Is my result undefined?  - "ERROR Invoke Error {"errorType":"SyntaxError","errorMessage":"Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0","stack":["SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0","    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)"

Comment: Jason, is it possible for you to send me the sample JSON? Moreover, can you stringify the event JSON and then parse it?

Comment: @HassanMurtaza {
  "phoneNumber": "+11231231234",
  "sub": [
    {
      "Name": "Tillery"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Bob"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Let me test on my end please.

Comment: @HassanMurtaza and would I stringify the event like this? ```module.exports.create = (event, context, callback) => {
  const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
  var dataStringify = JSON.stringify(event.body);
  //const data = JSON.parse(event.body);
  const data = JSON.parse(dataStringify); ```Thanks

Comment: So Jason, first of all if you see the JSON there's no "body" key that you're trying to parse. No need to use event.body. Just use event. Secondly, the input from AWS test event is already JSON Object and you don't need to parse it again. Please remove JSON.parse and just console the event. Let me know if it helped.

Comment: Let me know if it helped. I'll post this as an answer so that it help other people as well :).

Comment: @HassanMurtaza Thanks! it worked. Post it and I will vote it up

Comment: Sure, I have posted it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all if you see the JSON that you have provided:

`{ "phoneNumber": "+11231231234", "sub": [ { "Name": "Tillery" }, { "Name": "Bob" } ] }`

There's no **body** key. You can just use **event** instead of **event.body**. Like

`console.log(event);`

The input from AWS test event is already JSON Object and you don't need to parse it again.

Please remove JSON.parse and you'll be good.

Thanks!